# How to perform REST operations through a controller and JSP page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

This is a spring boot application, with JPA, JSP and MVC.

If I click the link in the below JSP, it is redirecting to the controller and then the controller is directing to the getAllItem method which goes to the Service. But, I get the below error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Cannot invoke "com.sportyshoes.basepackage.service.ShoeService.findAll()" because "this.shoeService" is null

but the REST is performing and the data is showing up in an application called **Advanced REST client** like Postman, but I am not able to retrieve the data through the controller. Please could anyone give your feedback on how to retrieve the data from database.

**my JSP is:**

`<a href="getallitem" name="getallitem">View all items</a>`

**My controller code as below:**

```
@Controller
public class WareHouseController {

    private ShoeService shoeService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/getallitem", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllItem() {
        List allShoes =  shoeService.findAll();
        System.out.println(allShoes);
        return "warehouse";
    }
}
```

**my Service is:**

```
public interface ShoeService {
    
    public List<ShoeData> findAll();
//  public ShoeData findByItemName(String shoename);
    public ShoeData insertData(ShoeData shoeData);
    public ShoeData deleteById(long theId);
    public ShoeData findById(long theId);
}
```

Comment: You are perhaps missing an `@Inject` annotation on `shoeService`. And JSP is a bad choice for doing REST stuff in '22, you'd rather want plain HTML + jQuery for that (just an example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing this for a certification project. I have to find another way to do it. Do you have any clear cut way to implement.